# Need help with Lebesgue measures and continuity

Tags: measure-theory

Let $E\subset\Bbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue measurable set such that $\lambda(E)<\infty$ and $a,b\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $a<b$.

(a) Prove that $f(x):=\lambda([a,x]\cap E)$ is continuous in $[a,b]$.

(b) With an extra assumption that $E$ is bounded , show that for any $0<\epsilon<\lambda(E)$, there exists a Lebesgue measurable set $F\subset E$ such that $\lambda(F)=\epsilon$.

(c) Prove part (b) without the assumption that $E$ is bounded.

For part (a) taking $\delta=\epsilon$, I got $|f(y)-f(z)|<\epsilon$ whereas $|y-z|<\delta$ i.e $f$ is continuous. (I can post here the whole works if anybody needs to see it). But the problem is with (b) and (c), I am totally clueless about how to prove those.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @PhoemueX, It would be very helpful if you could explain a little more. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You know that $f(a) = 0$ and $f(x) = \lambda(E)$ for $x$ large enough and $a$ small enough (if $E$ is bounded, you have $E \subset [a,b]$ for suitable $a,b$).

Now apply the intermediate value theorem.

For the case of possibly unbounded $E$, use the fact that $\lambda([-n,n] \cap E) \to \lambda(E)$. (Why does this hold?)